# Old movie like Inception where hero entered dreams?

Tags: story-identification, dreams

I remember an old movie (might have been a TV show, but I doubt it), which I only caught the end of:

A man (the president) is dreaming that he's on a train, looking out on a nuclear wasteland, and thinking that he caused it all. Hero (man) turns up and fights a baddie, and eventually defeats him and rescues president.

[end of scene]

Another baddie (probably big boss) confronts hero when lift doors open, and taunts him saying "You can't do anything to me". Hero says "Oh can't I?", and pulls his head open to reveal some sort of snake creature, which eats the boss baddie.

[end of scene]

Cut to hero waking up in room underneath big bosses office, with heroine and a device which they switch off, escape and fade to credits.

Anyone know what this film is? It's been bugging me for probably about 20 years.

Comment: You remember pieces of dialogue after 20 years?

Comment: Well, I can remember what I think they are, yes. I could be wrong. :)

Comment: Dude, your question bring me back the first scene, the president on a train, to my head! Great to remember it, i'll watch it again thanks to your question being answered

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This sounds like [Dreamscape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreamscape_%281984_film%29) starring Dennis Quaid.  It has all the elements you've described.  It's been awhile since I've seen it, but I'm almost 100% sure that's the one.

Comment: That's the one! You are a genius!

Comment: Based off the book The Dream Master - http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dream-Master-Nebula-Award-Winning-Novel/dp/0743413016

Comment: Actually the treatment for the film was written by the same Author as the Dream Master, however they are not the same story.

Comment: @Monty129 my bad!

Comment: I didn't know that either until I read the Wikipedia article myself!

Comment: That was a bad movie. That lizard monster was so lame.

Comment: Yeah the effects didn't age very well